# How to make sure Jackson is complaining when reading invalid YAML?

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, jackson, yaml

I want to parse YAML content and

- check whether the basic format rules are honored and
- check that the given structure matches my data class structure.

I know at least the YAML parser used by Spring Boot to read the application settings can throw such errors: [Found duplicate key in application.yml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74704616/found-duplicate-key-in-application-yml)

But, given an invalid YAML and read by a (simplified) code like:

```yaml
listblock:
  - name: "a"

listblock:  # DUPLICATE KEY!
  - name: "b"
    optional: "b optional"
```

```kotlin
    val yamlMapper = YAMLMapper().apply {
        registerKotlinModule()
    }

    @Test
    fun `yaml into jsonNode`() {
        val jsonNode = yamlMapper.readTree(invalidFile)
    }
```

No exception are thrown. The result is just containing the second `listblock`'s content.

To address my second sub-question: Even when using a data class structure, like:

```kotlin
data class ObjectDto(val listblock: List<ListElement>)

data class ListElement(val name: String, val optional: String?)
```

And read the YAML content like:

```kotlin
        val result = yamlMapper.readValue<ObjectDto>(invalidFile.readText())
```

There are still no problems occurring.

Please, check my MRE here: https://github.com/jakesmolka/jackson-yaml-problem/blob/main/src/test/kotlin/com/example/jacksonyamlproblem/JacksonYamlProblemApplicationTests.kt

Comment: `yamlMapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_READING_DUP_TREE_KEY );` but I don't know how to write it in Kotlin.

Comment: Thanks, @flyx, this works! Strange that Jackson allows reading invalid structures per default. I'm wondering what other flags I have to manually set to achieve a thorough format checking (without considering the data nor my data structure yet).

Comment: Note: This only works with `readTree` (or other ways of reading into tree). Reading into an object like in my MRE isn't affected by this flag. The general problems stays the same. (Of course, I can solve it in my actual code now, by first parsing into a tree and then an object.)

Comment: Jackson uses SnakeYAML for parsing, which has a [setAllowDuplicateKeys](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.yaml/snakeyaml/1.33/org/yaml/snakeyaml/LoaderOptions.html#setAllowDuplicateKeys-boolean-) which is enabled by default possibly for backwards compatibility with YAML 1.1. Afaik Jackson doesn't expose this so you can't set it if you use Jackson's API, however SnakeYAML also can deserialize into class instances so that's probably the better API to use if you need fine-tuning.